# Alternative to Google alerts that cover mentions for more than just news articles?

Tags: internet

I am looking for a tool similar to [Google Alerts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Alerts), but one that would track mentions more than just within news article. I'm looking for something that would track social media mentions, and other things within the web. Something that has more "reach" than Google Alerts.

I would like it to operate just like Google Alerts, where I can simply type in a word, and it would detect mentions for it on the web - Google Alerts is a free web service, and it works via Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

You’re not going to find a lone app/service that will search everything that you want.  For Twitter, I’ve found that setting up searches in TweetDeck works the best for me.  For blogs, forums, and other social media, I use a combination of Google Alerts, TalkWalker, and SEMrush.  There are a few other tools I use, but they only occasionally find something that the others did not.  Basically, you are going to have to play with a bunch of different tools until you find the mix that is right for you.

Comment: Thank you sir, great answer. Could you please suggest more? Specifically, for Instagram, mentions on the web, and news articles.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven’t found anything that works well with Instagram. Then again, I haven’t spent a lot of time looking for a tool for it since Instagram is not something important to me. For the others that you mention, Google Alerts and TalkWalker have served me well.  The trick with those services is coming up with good search terms. It took me a while to figure out that using compound search terms, usually returned better results than using single search terms.  Again, this requires experimentation to find what works best for you.

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate it. However the problem is, I've noticed that Google Alerts doesn't cover *everything* and ignores some social media platforms. Any solution? :)

Comment: As I pointed out, there is nothing that will work with everything. And there are lots of things (e.g. Facebook) that try to block/restrict external search bots (e.g. Google Alerts) from searching their site. In those cases, you will most likely have to resort to using whatever search capabilities that site has available. However, I have found that TalkWalker does a pretty good job of finding things here on Reddit, but that’s about the only social media platform it does well with.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions: I am looking for something that particularly tracks mentions for Facebook!

Comment: I’ve yet to find any external tools that work with Facebook.  If you find any then please post them here.  Whenever I want to search FB, I have to resort to using their built-in search bar and manually typing in my search terms.